# VB.Net dataconverter for controlbinding to a dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, ivalueconverter

I have a dataset which I create runtime (to be able to have multiple instances of that dataset) when an instance of a form is created. On this form are several textboxes with a databinding to the dataset.

Some values needs to be displayed different in the textbox then how they are stored in the dataset (and users must be able to change the value in the textbox and as such update the value in the dataset).

I created a converter class that implements IValueConverter (after hours of looking, I found that I also needed to reference PresentationFramework in PresentationFramework.dll) but now I do have a converter.

But how do I tell my databinding to use that convertor?

some code on creation of my form:

```
Public Sub Init()
        Dim data As DataSet
        Dim tblTest As DataTable

        'create data structure
        data = New DataSet("MyData")

        tblTest = New DataTable("Test")
        tblTest.Columns.Add("test1")
        tblTest.Columns.Add("test2")
        tblTest.Columns.Add("test3")

        data.Tables.Add(tblTest)

        'Bind datastructure
        txtTest1.DataBindings.Add("text", data, "MyData.test1")
        txtTest2.DataBindings.Add("text", data, "MyData.test2")
        txtTest3.DataBindings.Add("text", data, "MyData.test3")

    End Sub
```

My IDataConverter code:

```
Public Class MyValueConverter
    Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object,
                            ByVal targetType As System.Type,
                            ByVal parameter As Object,
                            ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
             As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert

        Return "X" & value

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object,
                                ByVal targetType As System.Type,
                                ByVal parameter As Object,
                                ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
            As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack

        Return value & "Y"
    End Function
End Class
```

(it just adds X or Y for debugging purposes and getting to understand how it works)

Does anybody know how I can tell it to use my converter in VB.Net (VS2010)? Please note that my bindings are created at runtime, so I have no xaml bindings to hack into...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Binding class has a Format and Parse events to handle your situation:

```
Private WithEvents TextBinding As Binding

Public Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()
  TextBinding = New Binding("Text", data.Tables("Test"), "test1")
  TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(TextBinding)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBinding_Format(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs) _
                               Handles TextBinding.Format
  e.Value = "X" & e.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBinding_Parse(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs) _
                              Handles TextBinding.Parse
  If e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Value.ToString.Length > 0 Then
    e.Value = e.Value.ToString.Substring(1)
  End If
End Sub
```